# Where is the proper place to store the access token in the Outlook add-in?

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, office-js, office-addins

We are using Office.js to build an Outlook add-in.
When receiving the access and refresh tokens using oauth 2.0, where is it secure and appropriate to keep the values?

- Using office.js functions

  - ```js
    Office.context.document.settings.set("access-token", "***");
    ```
  - ```js
    const _settings = Office.context.roamingSettings
    _settings.set("access-token", "***");
    ```
  - ```js
    Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync((asyncResult) => {
        const customProps = asyncResult.value;
        customProps.set("access-token", "***");
    }
    ```
- JavaScript

  - ```js
    localStorage.setItem("access-token", "***");
    ```
  - ```js
    document.cookie = "access-token=***";
    ```

I have considered the following options.

Is there any appropriate way to do any of these? Thanks.

Comment: For the Settings documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings says ```Don't store passwords and other sensitive personally identifiable information (PII) with the Settings object.```