# How to safely persist an oauth2 access token in my add-in

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

This question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698213/where-is-the-proper-place-to-store-the-access-token-in-the-outlook-add-in) but I believe it was not properly addressed and I have come up with the same concern a year later.

I'd like to use my own oauth provider authentication flow, and I'd like to understand what's the best user flow for getting the token from my server.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication#access-tokens-obtained-via-oauth2-flows), we need to use the `displayDialogAsync` method to open the oauth screen, which will send the authentication code to the backend, which it can decode and create a token that can be used for the Office add-in frontend.

However, there's no indication on how the backend can send this token to the frontend. Since setting a token cookie will not make it accessible from the add-in side. It seems the only way to grab it is by redirecting from the server to `https://localhost:3000/oauthResult/index.html?authToken=XXXX`. And that route can somehow store the token somewhere and then close the dialog.

So my main two questions are:

1. How to safely send the access token from the backend to the frontend without using a redirect with a cookie
2. Where to safely store within the Office Add-in ecosystem so that it can be picked up both by desktop and web clients? I know that I shouldn't use the Settings object to do so.

I tried using a redirect from my backend to my add-in frontend with the auth token set in a cookie, but that cookie was not available to be read from the add-in side later on.

Answer (score 0):

For your inspiration, see [Caching in MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/caching.md). MSAL.js is the Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript. MSAL.js is using the Web Storage API and can be configured to use either sessionStorage, localStorage or memoryStorage. As the article describe, the choice between different storage locations reflects a trade-off between better user experience vs. increased security.

Comment: This looks good. But I'm wondering if it's possible to access localStorage/sessionStorage on the Outlook desktop client. And again I can't find any example using social auth providers. It seems the authentication can only go through azure. I want to login with my own social auth provider

Comment: I don't see are reason that you wouldn't be able to use localStorage/sessionStorage in an add-in running in the Outlook desktop client. Try creating a snippet with Script Lab in Outlook to test it. Also, you can choose to write your own authentication logic. You don't need to use MSAL.js.